# How to write inputs from Fast Secure Contact Form to MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, contact-form

I'm using the PHP script version (not Wordpress) of Fast Secure Contact Form: http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/download-php-script. It works great, but I'm wondering how I would go about writing the form data to a MySQL database. For the Wordpress version, there is a Database extension, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/, but not for the PHP script. Any thoughts on how I could write the PHP script version inputs to a database would be much appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you'll need to workaround the codebase to modify it for saving inputs to a DB. But make sure it does not violate the "terms of use". By the way, what does it do with the inputs now - sends it to an email address?

Answer (score 0):

The website link you provided has some tip sections that discuss sending the data from the form to another page:

http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/sending-data-by-query-string

After entering the data in the form, you might be able to then send that data to another `PHP` page which can then save the data to a `MySQL` database.